# How to add commas to CountUp JS package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `CountUp` package for JS in React. You can find it [here](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup). The problem is that when a number is greater than 1000 it doesn't show it like this: `1,000` which would be my ideal solution.

This is code I have at the moment

```
$<CountUp decimal="," end={todaysStats.money_earned} duration={3} />
```

As you can see I tried adding `decimal=","` but it is not working.

In this case, I am counting up currency but it should work on any other number greater than 1000.

How do I approach this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation you need to use `separator` instead of decimal

> separator: string Specifies character of thousands separator.

https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup#separator-string

Comment: Jeez, thanks! I should really read the documentation more next time. I saw decimal and instantly thought it should be it. BTW Gonna accept the answer in 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

```
<CountUp start={animate ? 100.000 : null} end={200.000} duration={1} separator=" " decimals={3}
                decimal="," redraw={true}>
            {({ countUpRef }) => (
              <div>
                <span ref={countUpRef} className="number" />
                <VisibilitySensor
                  onChange={isVisible => {
                    if (isVisible) {
                      setAnimate(true);
                    } 
                  }}
                >
                  <span className="subtext" > members</span>
                </VisibilitySensor>
              </div>
            )}
          </CountUp>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**

- `<CountUp separator=',' delay={2} end={7000} />`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup